# JQuery DateTime Picker in JQuery Modal Dialog

Tags: modal-dialog, return-value, datetimepicker

Hi I am using JQuery DatetimePicker and want this to be in JQuery Modal dialog box as "inline" with two external buttons not of dialog box. On button click I want to return the date and time to parent window's input box.

How this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access that through a normal JQuery.
$("#YourControl").val(...);

Should work.

Comment: As the datetimepicker is "inline" so its applied on a simple div.